# Error in overriding virtual function in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17, pure-virtual

I am having issues with overriding a pure virtual function [getContents()]:
I am trying to inherit a class, fpmessage with a derived class fpmessageImpl

However, the compiler is reporting that fpmessageImpl is virtual when I try to instantiate it, due to getContents() being an unimplemented pure virtual function (despite having no issues with the override).  What is happening here, and is there a way to fix it?
Last section of clang++ error report: (offending code in fpmessagingSystemImpl has been moved to main in MWE)

```
src/fpmessagingsystemimpl.h:56:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'fp::utils::fpmessagingSystemImpl<fp::utils::fpMessagingDataStates::States>::send_message' requested here
      fpmessagingSystemImpl(std::map<MessageType,std::type_index> m) noexcept :
      ^
src/fpengineimpl.h:19:21: note: in instantiation of member function 'fp::utils::fpmessagingSystemImpl<fp::utils::fpMessagingDataStates::States>::fpmessagingSystemImpl' requested here
      msg_sys = new fp::utils::fpmessagingSystemImpl<fp::utils::fpMessagingDataStates::States>(ds.get_map());
                    ^
src/fpmessagingsystem.h:32:48: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'getContents' in 'fpmessage'
      virtual std::tuple<MessageType,std::any> getContents() const noexcept = 0;
```

Reproducible example:
Issue appears to be with how std::make_shared is constructing a new fpmessage (in main):

```
#include <memory>
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <typeindex>

class fpMessagingDataStates {
public:
  enum class States{
    INIT
  };
  const std::map<fpMessagingDataStates::States,std::type_index> get_map() {
    return m;
  }
  fpMessagingDataStates(){
    m = std::map<fpMessagingDataStates::States,std::type_index>();
    m.emplace(std::make_pair(fpMessagingDataStates::States::INIT,std::type_index(typeid(std::wstring))));
  }
private:
  std::map<fpMessagingDataStates::States,std::type_index> m;
};

template<typename MessageType>
class fpmessage{
public:
  fpmessage(MessageType mt, std::any a) noexcept {};
  virtual bool validate_message (const std::map<MessageType,std::type_index>& map) const noexcept {return false;}
  virtual std::tuple<MessageType,std::any> getContents() const noexcept = 0;
  /*virtual ~fpmessage();*/
protected:
  fpmessage() {};
};

template<typename MessageType>
class fpmessageImpl : public fpmessage<MessageType>{
public:
  fpmessageImpl() = delete;
  fpmessageImpl(MessageType mt, std::any a) :
    t(mt),
    contents(a) {}
  // check stored message type against a map
  virtual bool validate_message(const std::map<MessageType,std::type_index>& map) const noexcept override{
    // check the expected message type against the actual type
    auto expected_type = map.find(t);
    return (expected_type->second == std::type_index(contents.type()));
  }
  virtual std::tuple<MessageType,std::any> getContents() const noexcept override {
    return std::make_tuple(t,contents);
  }
private:
  const MessageType t;
  const std::any contents;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::wstring s = L"Engine Started";
  auto state = fpMessagingDataStates::States::INIT;
  auto m = fpmessageImpl<fpMessagingDataStates::States>(state, s);
  auto mess = std::make_shared<fpmessage<fpMessagingDataStates::States>>(m);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any definition for `fpmessage<T>::~fpmessage()`?

Comment: Please include error messages verbatim instead of paraphrasing

Comment: A destructor has not been defined (presumed using the default one)

Comment: Which compiler and which version are you using? On Linux GCC 7.2.0, your code works.

Comment: And what about the `fpmessagingSystemImpl` class mentioned in the error?

Comment: Can you please transform this to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: clang++ 5.0 with mingw-w64 (gcc v. 7.2) on windows

Comment: As  @Cornstalks said, please provide a **reproducible example**.

Comment: @Cheers and hth,@Cornstalks: working on a reproducible example.  First impressions are that without the other attached things it is working, so I'm going to gradually add things until it fails

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Apologies for missing that, and thank you for pointing it out.  The error came from that system.  The relevant code has been incorporated into the main function in EDIT2

Comment: `auto mess = 
    std::make_shared<fpmessage<fpMessagingDataStates::States>>(m); `<- If I'm not mistaken you are trying to instantiate fpmessage which is abstract, you might want to do something like this 
    `std::shared_ptr<fpmessage<fpMessagingDataStates::States>> mess = std::make_shared<fpmessageImpl<fpMessagingDataStates::States>>(m);` instead

Comment: Please stop bloating the question. You don't need to keep a full history of it. Just post the minimal example and your question, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 auto m = fpmessageImpl<fpMessagingDataStates::States>(state, s);
 auto mess = std::make_shared<fpmessage<fpMessagingDataStates::States>>(m);
```

Renaming and simplifying for illustrative purposes:

```
auto d = Derived();
auto bp = std::make_shared<Base>(d);
```

This is a glorified c++11-style wrapper around the old good

```
 Derived d;
 Base* pb = new Base(d);
```

The second line will not create an object of type `Derived`. It will create an object of type `Base` and copy-construct it from the `Derived` argument, slicing it in process. And of course it will fail to compile if `Base` is abstract.

In order to copy `d` one would need to

```
Base* pb = new Derived(d);
```

or in C++11-parlance

```
 std::shared_ptr<Base> = std::make_shared<Derived>(d);
```

Comment: I have a function: fn(const Base& b){auto a = make_shared<Base>(b);}. Is there some way of directly copying (by memory or otherwise) a Derived which is passed to this function so as to be able to create a?  Eg. Clone into a shared_ptr?

Comment: @DavidTurner `make_shared<Base>(anything)` creates a new `Base` so it won't help you. If  you need a new `Derived`, you need to have a call to `make_shared<Derived>(..)` somewhere. Perhaps in a virtual `clone` method.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking at an implementation with virtual clone_shared function in base, and using a std::dynamic_pointer_cast in the inherited method.